# run a particular appilcation after logging on to remote PC using logmein

Tags: logmein

I'm using logmenin to connect to remote computers. Is it possible to configure logmein to automatically run a particular program after a successful log in?

Thanks

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the remote computer is a Windows box (and also assuming that you are doing a fresh login each time you connect and not just connecting to an existing session (is it considered RDP?)), can't you just add a shortcut to the program in your startup folder?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7

If you are not using Windows that is obviously not going to help. Either way, you need to give more detail.